# Can't control Snake movement, Snake kill always itself by ran into the wall. c#

Tags: c#

I'm a total beginner and wanted to programm Snake. For that I go step by step trough a tutorial and when I start the game now the snake always goes straight to a wall and dies. I was searching a lot and ask friends but still no idea where the problem is.
I hope someone here can help me. Here is the code:

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Snake__Die_hungrige_Schlange
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Circle> Snake = new List<Circle>();
        private Circle food = new Circle();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        new Settings();

        SpielzeitTimer.Interval = 1000 / Settings.Speed;
        SpielzeitTimer.Tick += updateScreen;
        SpielzeitTimer.Start();

        startGame();
    }

    private void updateScreen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Settings.GameOver == true)
        {
            if (Input.KeyPress(Keys.Enter))
            {
                startGame();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Input.KeyPress(Keys.Right) && Settings.direction != Directions.Left)
            {
                Settings.direction = Directions.Right;
            }
            else if (Input.KeyPress(Keys.Left) && Settings.direction != Directions.Right)
            {
                Settings.direction = Directions.Left;
            }
            else if (Input.KeyPress(Keys.Up) && Settings.direction != Directions.Down)
            {
                Settings.direction = Directions.Up;
            }
            else if (Input.KeyPress(Keys.Down) && Settings.direction != Directions.Up)
            {
                Settings.direction = Directions.Down;
            }

            movePlayer();
        }

        pbCanvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private void movePlayer()
    {
        for (int i = Snake.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                switch (Settings.direction)
                {
                    case Directions.Right:
                        Snake[i] .X++;
                        break;
                    case Directions.Left:
                        Snake[i] .X--;
                        break;
                    case Directions.Up:
                        Snake[i] .Y--;
                        break;
                    case Directions.Down:
                        Snake[i] .Y++;
                        break;
                }

                int maxXpos = pbCanvas.Size.Width / Settings.Width;
                int maxYpos = pbCanvas.Size.Height / Settings.Height;

                if (
                    Snake[i].X < 0 || Snake[i].Y < 0 ||
                    Snake[i].X > maxXpos || Snake[i].Y > maxYpos
                    )
                {
                    die();
                }

                for (int j = 1; j < Snake.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (Snake[i].X == Snake[j].X && Snake[i].Y == Snake[j].Y)
                    {
                        die();
                    }
                }

                if (Snake[0].X == food.X && Snake[0].Y == food.Y)
                {
                    eat();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Snake[i].X = Snake[i - 1].X;
                Snake[i].Y = Snake[i - 1].Y;
            }
        }
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void keyisdown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Input.changeState(e.KeyCode, true);
    }

    private void keyisup(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Input.changeState(e.KeyCode, false);
    }

    private void updateGraphics(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;

        if (Settings.GameOver == false)
        {
            Brush snakeColour;
            for (int i = 0; i < Snake.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {

                    snakeColour = Brushes.Purple;
                }
                else
                {
                    snakeColour = Brushes.Black;
                }

            canvas.FillEllipse(snakeColour,
                                new Rectangle(
                                    Snake[i].X * Settings.Width,
                                    Snake[i].Y * Settings.Height,
                                    Settings.Width, Settings.Height
                                    ));


            canvas.FillEllipse(Brushes.Azure,
                                new Rectangle(
                                    food.X * Settings.Width,
                                    food.Y * Settings.Height,
                                    Settings.Width, Settings.Height
                                    ));
            }

    }
    else
    {
        string gameOver = "Game Over\n" + "Erreichte Punktzahl ist " + Settings.Score + "\n Drücke Enter zum Neustarten \n";
        label3.Text = gameOver;
        label3.Visible = true;
    }
}      
    private void startGame()
    {
        label3.Visible = false;
        new Settings();
        Snake.Clear();
        Circle head = new Circle { X = 10, Y = 5 };
        Snake.Add(head);

        PunktestandLabel.Text = Settings.Score.ToString();

        generateFood();
    }

    private void generateFood()
    {
        int maxXpos = pbCanvas.Size.Width / Settings.Width;
        int maxYpos = pbCanvas.Size.Height / Settings.Height;

        Random rnd = new Random();
        food = new Circle { X = rnd.Next(0, maxXpos), Y = rnd.Next(0, maxYpos) };
    }

    private void eat ()
    {
        Circle body = new Circle
        {
            X = Snake[Snake.Count - 1].X,
            Y = Snake[Snake.Count - 1].Y
        };

        Snake.Add(body);
        Settings.Score += Settings.Points;
        PunktestandLabel.Text = Settings.Score.ToString();
        generateFood();
    }

    private void die()
    {
        Settings.GameOver = true;
    }

    private void BeendenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

}
```

Input.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Snake__Die_hungrige_Schlange
{
    class Input
    {
        private static Hashtable keyTable = new Hashtable();

        public static bool KeyPress(Keys key)
        {
            if (keyTable[key] == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (bool)keyTable[key];
        }

        public static void changeState(Keys key, bool state)
        {
            keyTable[key] = state;
        }
    }
}
```

Settings.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Snake__Die_hungrige_Schlange
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        Left,
        Right,
        Up,
        Down
    };

    class Settings
    {
        public static int Width { get; set; }
        public static int Height { get; set; }
        public static int Speed { get; set; }
        public static int Score { get; set; }
        public static int Points { get; set; }
        public static bool GameOver { get; set; }
        public static Directions direction { get; set; }

        public Settings()
        {
            Width = 16;
            Height = 16;
            Speed = 10;
            Score = 0;
            Points = 100;
            GameOver = false;
            direction = Directions.Down;
        }

    }
}
```

Circle.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Snake__Die_hungrige_Schlange
{
    class Circle
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Circle()
        {
            X = 0;
            Y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So that was all. Sorry for this mass of text, but I hope some of you may know the answer.
Thanks :)

Here is the Link:
https://www.mooict.com/c-tutorial-create-a-classic-snake-game-in-visual-studio/

Comment: I would first  double check to make sure the Forms KeyDown() and KeyUp() events are properly wired up to the key handlers as specified in the tutorial instructions.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `Input.changeState(e.KeyCode, true);` Does it ever get hit? If not then @Idle_Mind is almost certainly correct.

Comment: Does `Input.KeyPress` wait for user input? Because you're only checking the input during your tick, which means that if a user presses and releases the key between two ticks, it's not going to get captured.

Comment: @mjwills I just looked again and no it doesn't even hit the breakpoint

Comment: Then @Idle_Mind is correct.